# Changing text color in UICollectionView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UICollectionView with cells that contain UILabels that update dynamically. When I select a cell, I have the background color of the cell change, but I want the text color in the label to change as well. Currently, I'm using the following code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("targetCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
    var label : UILabel = cell.viewWithTag(100) as UILabel
    label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

However, on selecting the cell, the text color does not update with the new color. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are dequeuing a reusable cell and update it.

Basically, `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` is only used in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`.

Use `cellForItemAtIndexPath` to get the selected cell.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
        let label = cell.viewWithTag(100) as? UILabel
        label?.textColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```